I have to delete /var/lib/pacman/sync each boot to make pacman work
Every time I reboot, pacman gives me the same error:

Cannot prepare transaction, invalid or corrupted database.

Then I delete /var/lib/pacman/sync and it will work again until the next reboot.
How to fix this permanently? I suspect there is some funky package causing this, but I don't know how to track it down.

Are you interrupting a pacman command before it has a chance to clean up after itself?

no I use it normally
